# Loading a PHP file to a div with the same submit button click while submitting data

Tags: php, jquery, html

Helo.... I need to submit a form. In the same time with the same submit button I need to load the relevant php file in to a target div. This is an dummy question that I have tried.

```
<form id='A' method="POST" action="CreateTheForm.php">
<input id="B" name="R"></input>
<input id="C" name="SubmitBtn" type="submit" value="loading the vaue"></input>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#C").click(function() {
    $("#Loading_Page").load('CreateTheForm.php');
      return false;
  });
});
```

But though I can load the CreateTheForm.php file to the Loading_Page div, the data are not posting and I cant access them from CreateTheForm.php file.

What I need to do is first I should post data to the php file and load it to the relevant div with the same click. How can I make this possible.

This works well without the load function.

Comment: u want "b" value in CreateTheForm.php?

Comment: yes... b is what I need to receive.

Comment: Have u posted "b" value in that page?

Comment: Didn't look like that in your code..Can you post the code of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) Request and grab the content as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#C" ).click(function() {
   $.post( "CreateTheForm.php", { R: $('#B').val() }, function(data){
       $('#Loading_Page').html(data);
   });
   return false;

});
});
```

Comment: Hi this gives what I need.. Thanx alot for answering.. Cant't I submit the whole form using this way? And hope I do not need to mention method="POST" action="CreateTheForm.php in the form. But what would happen if my form is complex and if I need to post may data? Is the same way we have used possible?

Comment: just replace `{ R: $('#B').val() }` with `$( "#A" ).serialize()` :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not posting the data. To post the data you will need to use this.

```
$("#Loading_Page").load('CreateTheForm.php', {'R': $('#B').val()});
```

instead of

```
$("#Loading_Page").load('CreateTheForm.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
$( "#C" ).click(function() {
   $("#Loading_Page").load('CreateTheForm.php');
   $("#a").submit();
   return false;    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
$("#C").click(function () {

    $("#Loading_Page").load('CreateTheForm.php');
    $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
    return false;

});
```

Comment: What does this  $(this).closest('form')[0].submit(); If this form named the form tag?

Comment: Will target the parent form (you could use the ID as selector) then return the DOM node ([0]) to submit it using native JS event, not jquery handler